# I can't suspend, reboot, shutdown in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, shutdown

I've bought a new acer aspire e14 laptop and installed ubuntu 15.04 but my problem is that I can't shutdown, suspend or reboot. it goes in the normal process the screen turn off but the led is always on, and the HDD never turn off.

I pressed esc while shutdown and the last message is

```
[83.973836] systemd_shutdown[1]: failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot and Shutdown Issues on Aspire E 11 model E3-111-C0WA](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524894/boot-and-shutdown-issues-on-aspire-e-11-model-e3-111-c0wa)

Comment: tried that didn't work either

Comment: I suggest using upstart instead of `systemd` or install Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: ok how to do that?

Comment: Enter grub menu by pressing Shift or ESC while booting and select upstart there.

Comment: negative.. I am considering downgrading to 14.04 but I'm not sure that will help

Comment: I am not sure either, but that solution seems to work in 14.04.

Comment: I've almost tried every linux distro, all of them did the same except lubuntu 14.04 32-bit, it works!

Comment: I have this exact same problem with a upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, plus I also added sda3_crypt disk encryption - cannot find a solution. restart works fine but shutdown hangs with the same final error msg

Answer (score 0):

try # init 0 or poweroff for shutdown.

try # init 6 for reboot.

Comment: didnt work, however init 0 left me in the shutdown animation (the animation hangs and still hanged this forever)

Comment: Try above commands with sudo. after this if it does not work then try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.

Comment: no nothing works