# Lubuntu doesn't poweroff/reboot

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown

I just have aproximately 3 days in Ubuntu. I have Lubuntu, I tried a lot of solutions for solve the hang which I'm experimenting when I try to PowerOff/ Reboot my Computer, I have a Aser  Aspire E-11. Any solutions? Thanks.

Solution of @Woojoo solutionate everything.

**I have Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS**

Comment: Open a terminal window and type `sudo poweroff`, input your password when prompted, then press enter. (You will not get any feedback at all when entering the password.) Copy any messages printed in the terminal window and edit them into your question.

Comment: Hello. @OrganicMarble It's works but I would like to do it from the button in the desk. How I could do this? I have Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting an answer is enough to mark a question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Terminal and enter:

```
sudo reboot now
```

to force a direct reboot or

```
sudo shutdown -P
```

to shutdown and poweroff the maschine

Comment: Works, thanks @wooJoo I would like to solve the problem and do it from the button in pc. ¡could be there any solution?

Comment: @Luigi-Lopez [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524894/boot-and-shutdown-issues-on-aspire-e-11-model-e3-111-c0wa) i think this might help you solve your problem. If you apply the changes from this post the changes will take effect after you restarted the system.

Comment: Thanks A LOT @WooJoo I SOLVE IT Aser E-11 I wen to blacklist.conf and added what you give in the Link. The solution for Hanging on shutdown in Lubuntu and suspension when close laptop. I will edit the question with all the steps for others, later. Thanks.

Comment: @LuigiLopez Please don't include the solution you found directly into your question, but write a separate answer to your own question yourself. That's the format of a Q&A site which we want to have here to keep the quality high and the structure clear. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. PS: If you haven't already done that, consider investing two minutes to take the [tour], which will show you the basic elements about how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

*STEPS I DID TO SOLVE*

- Press CTRL + ALT + T
- In terminal type `sudo xedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- At the bottom of the file add:

  ```
  blacklist dw_dmac
  blacklist dw_dmac_core
  ```
- Save and Quit
- Type `sudo xedit /etc/default/grub`
- In the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` erase `quiet
  splash`
- Save and Quit
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot once

I did it and the PC now can PowerOff/Reboot/Suspend and everything.

Notes: This worked for ACER E-11 with previous Windows8.1 and now with Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

*Cons: During Start or ShutDown the computer will show only console, but it'll work.*